# Ubuntu Touch: how to create a launcher to start a shell script?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, launcher, scripts, bq

On my bq Aquaris E4.5 I want to create a launcher button for the App Scope to start a shell script. Is there an easy way to create such a launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one works on my bq aquaris 4.5:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=aa-exec -- ssh -T pi@raspi2 francebleu.sh
Icon=/home/phablet/.local/share/icons/francebleustart.png
Name=FranceBleu Start
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
X-Ubuntu-Default-Department-ID=accessories
```

Comment: it can be placed in .local/share/applications/<yourstarter>.desktop